# Java: Splitting string by tabs eliminates blank spaces

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to split a string by tab spaces. However, even when I specify a negative limit argument, splitting the string omits the blank spaces. Below is my input, code, as well as output.

Input:

```
String line = "asbd    asd\dse            NULL    NULL"
```

Code:

```
String[] components = line.split("\t+", -1);
System.out.println("components = " + Arrays.toString(components));
```

Output:

```
components = ["asbd", "asd\dse", "NULL", "NULL"]
```

As shown above, empty spaces are omitted from the output, as there are multiple tabs between the string `asd\dse` and `NULL`.

Comment: there are no tabs in string you provided, can you give actual one?

Comment: Are there space characters in the original string that you're trying to have show up in `components`?  Or are there multiple tab characters, and you're trying to have empty _strings_ (`""`) show up in `components`?

Comment: @rgettman There are definitely no space characters in the original string, it's just hard to format tabs with StackOverflow

Comment: @IlyaBursov There are definitely no space characters in the original string, it's just hard to format tabs with StackOverflow

Comment: Remove the `+` from the regular expression.  `+` means "one or more", so it's treating two consecutive tabs as a single delimiter.  I think you're saying you want two .consecutive tabs to be treated as two delimiters, with an empty string between.

Comment: @Adam Lee why can't you replace \ with / and then split with / ?

Comment: programmatically, obvius